# How to create a program in c++ to run on the desktop and use bitmaps in runtime from a programmer specified folder?

Tags: c++, bitmap, directory, executable, visual-studio-express

I'm new at this site and programming so please forgive me if I break any rules or sound stupid. Now I've said that,

We recently had to create a program in my cs1 class (intro to c++) simulating the game blackjack while using bitmaps to display the cards in the graphics window. Now I want to run the program as an executable on my desktop. However when I put the executable on the desktop from the debug project folder and run it the program crashes because it can't find the bitmaps. Any suggestion on how to do this but having the folder of bitmaps somewhere else?
The program is runs fine in the compiler I'm using, Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.
Thank you in advance for any help!

Edit: I uploaded the source code in question. I would have uploaded the entire program but the program is close to 500 lines...

It works fine within the compiler but once I move the exe outside of the project folder the program can not find the bmps. We have to use the displayCard() function to display the card. That causes a problem since I don't know how it works (other than implementing the the function in the code) since it comes from the GLUT files we had to add to Visual Studio.

```
//Display graphics of the cards according to the x/y coordinates and the assigned  card values from the deal function.
void displayCard(int card, int x, int y)
{
switch (card)
{
    case 2 : displayBMP("h2.bmp", x, y);
             break;
    case 3 : displayBMP("h3.bmp", x, y);
             break;
    case 4 : displayBMP("h4.bmp", x, y);
             break;
    case 5 : displayBMP("h5.bmp", x, y);
             break;
    case 6 : displayBMP("h6.bmp", x, y);
             break;
    case 7 : displayBMP("h7.bmp", x, y);
             break;
    case 8 : displayBMP("h8.bmp", x, y);
             break;
    case 9 : displayBMP("h9.bmp", x, y);
             break;
    case 10 : displayBMP("h10.bmp", x, y);
              break;
    case 11 : displayBMP("hj.bmp", x, y);
              break;
    case 12 : displayBMP("hq.bmp", x, y);
              break;
    case 13 : displayBMP("hk.bmp", x, y);
              break;
    case 14 : displayBMP("ha.bmp", x, y);
              break;
}
}
```

Comment: How are you specifying the file and folder path? is it using current directory or hard coded?

Comment: We didn't specify it in the program, we only had to put the bitmaps in where the source code is. So I'm guessing it's using the current directory...?

Comment: If no path is specified then How are the bitmaps fetched and loaded? out of air?

Comment: It is being fetched by the function displayBMP("name_of_image", x, y); We are using the graphLib1.lib and graph1.h. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I don't know what the directory the function is using since it is a function I didn't create. I'll look at the header file and see if I can find it.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check to see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the path of the bitmaps correctly in your program. If it is a relative path like ..\bitmaps then you should place the bitmaps inside a folder where your exe is residing.

I would suggest to have a configuration file and specify the path of the bitmaps in there.

Another alternative is to load the bitmaps into your resource file and read it from there.

Comment: I think there is also an option to embed the bitmaps

Comment: Thank you. Would you give me an example how I would do that? Such as where and/or when? I can upload the source code if need be (if there is a way to do it on this site)

Comment: @user1287469 paste the source code of the line which loads the bitmap

Answer (score 0):

There must be some line of code in your program that load the bitmaps from the specified folder(path) to the memory. 
Relative path is a path relative to the working directory of the user or application, so the full absolute path will not have to be given.
1) If its relative path used then place everything, ie: exe, resource files etc in the same folder.

2) If its a hard coded path then you have tp place the supporting files like bitmaps in that path itself.

3) And since you are using Visual Studio, you can actually place bitmaps as resource files. for that you go to add resource. you can read about it in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zabda143.aspx).

4) What i think as the best is using of config files. they are simpler to change and use.

EDIT:
Instead of: `displayBMP("name_of_image", x, y);`
Use: `displayBMP("path_of_image", x, y);` 
eg of path: `c:\abc\xyj.bmp`

Comment: Or you can try relative path too, based on current directory. But 1st make sure this one works. If this doesnt work it must be some other problem.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but that still didn't work. Not sure what to do now....

Comment: What are the troubles you experiencing?

Comment: I would like to put an exe of the program I wrote on my desktop so I can play it whenever I want to instead of running visual studio, load the source code into visual studio, compile the source code, THEN play it. I tried to put the exe that came from the compiler directly onto the desktop, however, during run time the exe can not find the bmps.

Comment: If the path is hard coded as the compiler generated path then moving .exe wont be a problem.